# Ubuntu on VMWare freezes on startup

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, virtual-machine, vmware

Problem started when I installed new updates with Software Updater and shutdown the virtual machine.

### Problem:

Now when I start the virtual machine, it freezes before login so that only purple background is shown.

I can use the virtual machine if I set `nomodeset` in GRUB,
but resolution is limited to `1176 x 885 (4:3)`

### Research:

I have another Virtual Ubuntu ( both 18.04.2 ) and when compared only difference is graphics driver.

Virtual Ubuntu with this problem:

```
Graphics: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 256 bits)
```

Virtual Ubuntu that works:

```
SVGA3D;build;RELEASE;LLVM;
```

I also run this command:

```
grep "vmware" /var/log/Xorg.0.log |head -17| cut -d\: -f2
```

[image: Ubuntu Graphics Driver Error]

### Info:

```
VMware: 
    Product: VMware® Workstation 15 Player
    Version: 15.1.0 build-13591040

Host PC:
    OS: Windows 10 Home Edition (64bit)
    CPU: Intel i5 8600K
    GPU: Nvidia GTX 1080

Quest OS:
    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (64bit)
```

### Question:

How can I fix this driver? (I found tutorials for nvidia drivers only)

Or should I just create a new virtual machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1832138
Resolved the issue I was having with similar setup.

From the other Website:

> I've found that I can work around the hang/freeze if I **uncomment** the following line in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`;
>
> ```
> #WaylandEnable=false
> ```
>
> After uncommenting the `WaylandEnable=false` line and rebooting, then I see the login prompt as expected and I can then log in and use the system normally again.

Comment: Thanks. I can get login screen now and full resolution.